# How to get the right demand in the newsvendor model?

Tags: python-2.7

So what I'm trying to accomplish is the newsvendor problem, where the program is supposed to run and give me the demand that gives me the best chances of turning a profit as per [this link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-772j-d-lab-supply-chains-fall-2014/calendar/MIT15_772JF14_Newsboy.pdf).

But the issue is that when I run the below code it gives me the right demand along with the demand for it.

```
q = {5:0.2 ,6:0.25 ,7:0.3 ,8:.25}
w = 55
p = 80
s = 40
cul5 = 0.2
cul6 = 0.25
cul7 = 0.3
cul8 = .25
overage = w - s
underage = p - w
crit = overage/float((underage)+(overage)) # its better to use floats within the parenthesis in python 2

cumul_q = {}
cumulativevalue = 0
for key, value in sorted(q.iteritems()):
    cumulativevalue = cumulativevalue + value
    # print key , value
    cumul_q[key] = cumulativevalue
    # print cumul_q

previous_key = None

for key, value, in sorted(cumul_q.iteritems(),reverse = True):
    cumulprob = 1 - value
    cumulprob1 = float(cumulprob)
    if crit < cumulprob1:
        continue
    elif crit > cumulprob1:
        print key
    previous_key = key
```

Comment: @compor: thanks for wanting to edit questions here. If you see chatty material like thanks, greetings, please-help-me, stuck-for-X-time pleading, you can just remove it rather than fixing it.

Comment: @halfer I'm usually doing so, but this one had several issues